# Error while running command

Tags: java, android

Getting Error while executing the below command

```
dz> run app.package.manifest jakhar.aseem.diva
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_65\bin\javac.exe -cp C:\Program Files\drozer\lib\drozer\lib\android.jar XmlAssetReader.java
javac: invalid flag: Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_65\bin\javac.exe
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
use -help for a list of possible options
Error whilst compiling the Java sources.
```

Comment: so, did you try the -help flag?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Visit: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask on tips on asking

Comment: What are you even trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the program `run` doesn't understand the space in `Program Files`:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_65\bin\javac.exe -cp C:\Program Files\drozer\lib\drozer\lib\android.jar XmlAssetReader.java
javac: invalid flag: Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_65\bin\javac.exe
```

It calls `javac`, which sees the `-cp` flag (for classpath). But javac doesn't realize that what follows is a single directory. It thinks the part from `Files\` onward is a new flag... that it doesn't know.

If you created this program `run` yourself, then the easiest solution is adapt that source - put double-quotes around the argument. So you'd get:

```
-cp "C:\Program Files\drozer\lib\drozer\lib\android.jar"
```

Alternatively, on a Windows machine, you may be able to use `Progra~1` as a shorthand for this directory. But off the top of my head that won't work on every Windows machine anymore.